# Controlling Multiple Charts with a Single Jquery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm working with the "Clustered Pie Charts" example (https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/XGRYYp) for AM Charts 4.  I've added multiple datasets for each chart and am trying to use the Jquery UI Slider to cycle through these datasets.  I'm basically trying to use the UI Slider to control multiple charts and the respective datasets for these charts. I can't seem to make the slider recognize the name of the dataset.  Definitely an issue with the slide function.  Does anyone have experience with this?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

I was able to pair a single slider to a single chart/dataset (https://codepen.io/greg-griffith/pen/Rwbmpga), but am not having much luck in trying to pair a single slider to multiple charts/datasets.

```js
// Create chart instance
var container = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4core.Container);
container.width = am4core.percent(100);
container.height = am4core.percent(100);
container.layout = "horizontal";

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_material);

function createChart(data) {

  // Create chart
  var chart = container.createChild(am4charts.PieChart);

  // Add data
  chart.data = data;

  // Add and configure Series
  var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
  pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
 // pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;
  //pieSeries.ticks.template.disabled = true;
  
};

createChart([
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 50},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income",value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 10},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 40},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 20},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 30},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value:40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 30},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 20},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 40},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 10},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", values: 50},
        
    ]);

createChart([
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 0.55},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 0.40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 0.07},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .50},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .14},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .45},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .21},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .40},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .28},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .35},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .35},
        
    ]);

createChart([
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 52},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 38},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 10},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .50},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .14},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .45},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .21},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .40},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .28},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .35},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .35},
        
    ]);



$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    //range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    value: 0,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = data[0];
      $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.category);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = data[ui.value];
      chart.data = dataSet;
      chart.validateData();
      $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
    },
    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/material.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div class="container">

<div id="chartdiv">
  
  
  </div>
 <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking over this, your data structure and attempts look on point. Slider works with integer values. One thing I do not see is here: `var dataSet = data[0];` where is `data` defined?

Comment: That's the spot that's tripping me up.  Not sure if the current array format will work with the UI Slider. Or, if it will, not exactly sure how to reference the dataset in the slider function. The method that AM Charts is using for this example formats the dataset a little differently than other examples.

Comment: Well I do not see where `data` is defined any place within scope fo the slider. Same with `chart`

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  In other examples, they explicitly define the array that drives the chart, such as "var chartData = array info."  In the multiple charts example, they don't follow this format.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be upfront, I have never used this library and looking at the docs, they were less than helpful.

Here is a basic working example:

```js
var dataset = [];
dataset.push([{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 50
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 10
    },
  ],
  // 40/40/20
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 20
    },

  ],
  // 30/40/30
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 30
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 30
    },

  ],
  // 20/40/40
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 20
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 40
    },

  ],
  // 10/40/50
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      values: 50
    },

  ]);
dataset.push([{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.55
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.07
    },
  ],
  // 40/40/20
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.50
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.14
    },

  ],
  // 30/40/30
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.45
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.21
    },

  ],
  // 20/40/40
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.28
    },

  ],
  // 10/40/50
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.35
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.35
    },

  ]);
dataset.push([{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 52
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 38
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 10
    },
  ],
  // 40/40/20
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.50
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.14
    },

  ],
  // 30/40/30
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.45
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.21
    },

  ],
  // 20/40/40
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.28
    },

  ],
  // 10/40/50
  [{
      country: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.35
    },
    {
      country: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      country: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.35
    }
  ]);

$(function() {
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_material);
  var container = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4core.Container);
  container.width = am4core.percent(100);
  container.height = am4core.percent(100);
  container.layout = "horizontal";

  function drawChart(d, c) {
    // Create chart
    var chart = c.createChild(am4charts.PieChart);

    // Add data
    chart.data = d;

    // Add and configure Series
    var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
    pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
    pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";

    return chart;
  }


  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    value: 0,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = dataset[0];
      $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.category);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var curDataSet = dataset[ui.value];
      var chart = drawChart(curDataSet, container);
      chart.validateData();
      $(ui.handle).text(curDataSet.category);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/material.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

It has some issues. For example, I suspect you want the chart to clear the current data before loading the next. I could not determine how this was done using either the chart or the container. So the charts pile up, but the data set is changing to the one desired.

You also have references to an index that does not appear to exist: `category`. I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with defining the dataset vars.  That's the key, I think. I'm going to tinker with it using your suggestion.  Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: @Griffigr great! If it helps, I hope you want to upvote it. If it answers the question, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by building out individual arrays and tying them back into the slide function.  The "Clusted Pie Charts" example from AM Charts is kinda crappy and deviates from typical methods for calling and building arrays.  Big thanks to @Twisty for pointing me in the right direction.

```js
function am4themes_myTheme(target) {
  if (target instanceof am4core.ColorSet) {
    target.list = [
      am4core.color("#0063a0"),
      am4core.color("#c0504d"),
      am4core.color("#51d3d0")
          ];
  }
}


// Set theme
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_myTheme);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);
var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4charts.PieChart);

var chartData = [
    // 50/40/10
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 50},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income",value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 10},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 40},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 20},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 30},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value:40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 30},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 20},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 40},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 10},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 50},
        
    ]
];

var chart2Data = [
    // 50/40/10
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: 0.55},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 0.40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 0.07},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .50},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .14},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .45},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .21},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .40},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .28},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { country: "U.S. Equities", value: .35},
        { country: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { country: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .35},
        
    ]
];

// Add data
chart.data = chartData[0];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";

// Let's cut a hole in our Pie chart the size of 40% the radius
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);

// Put a thick white border around each Slice
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#4a2abb");
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;


chart2.data = chart2Data[0];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries2 = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries2.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries2.dataFields.category = "country";

// Let's cut a hole in our Pie chart the size of 40% the radius
chart2.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);

// Put a thick white border around each Slice
pieSeries2.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#4a2abb");
pieSeries2.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
pieSeries2.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;


// Add a legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart2.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

function selectDataset(d) {
    chart.data = chartData[d];
    chart.validateData();
    chart.animateAgain();
}

function selectDataset2(d) {
    chart2.data = chart2Data[d];
    chart2.validateData();
    chart2.animateAgain();
}

var label = pieSeries2.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "${values.value.sum}";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = 40;

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    value: 0,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = (chartData[0],chart2Data[0]);
      $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.category);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = (chartData[ui.value]);
      var dataSet2 = (chart2Data[ui.value]);
      // var dataSet = (chartData[ui.value], chart2Data[ui.value]);
      chart2.data = dataSet2;
      chart.data = dataSet;
      chart2.validateData();
      chart.validateData();
      $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
    }
  });
});

$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value: 10,
    min: 10,
    max: 50,
    step: 10
})
.each(function() {

  //
  // Add labels to slider whose values 
  // are specified by min, max and whose
  // step is set to 1
  //

  // Get the options for this slider
  var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;
  
  // Get the number of possible values
  var vals = opt.max - opt.min;
  
  // Space out values
  for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {
    
    var el = $('<label>'+(i*10+10)+'%'+'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*1000)+'%');
  
    $( "#slider" ).append(el);
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

.container 
{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#chartdiv, #chartdiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}

#slider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider .ui-slider-handle {
  outline: 0;
  background: #c0504d;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: -.6em;
}

#slider.ui-slider-horizontal {
  top: 1em;
  left: 5%;
  height: .1em;
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="container">
<div style="width: 50%; float: left;" id="chartdiv"></div>
<div style="width: 50%; float: right;" id="chartdiv2"></div>
</div>
```